# How to disable showing recent files in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I didn't find any option in "preferences". How can I do it?

[image]

a screenshot of preferences in my notepad++:

[image]

Comment: which Version do you use ?!

Comment: I use version 6.2

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings >> Preferences >> Backup 

**Uncheck** the Remember Current Session for Next Launch

[image]

Comment: my "backup" section is different from what is shown in the image above. I will upload an image

Comment: which version do you use?

Comment: I found it in preferences>misc, but it only disables recent files shown in other tabs, not recent files in "file" menu (which I've shown in the image)

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the list of recent documents by changing your Recent Files History settings under

> Settings > Preferences > Recent Files History

[image]

While there is no an explicit "disable" feature, you can set the "Max. number of entries" to 0.

(I'm currently using Notepad++ v6.8.3)

Comment: Did it work on your machine? It doesn't work for me.

Comment: This works for me in 7.9.